# Css modal-dialog button label off center

Tags: html, css, flexbox, modal-dialog, popup

I am making an Apple macOS themed css library and am currently working on a popover modal using css flexbox.

The button is supposed to center the text inside of it. This is what i tried:

```css
/* Styling for the popover modal */
#popover {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 260px;
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(1);
}

#popover img.pop-img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#popover .btn-container {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 16px;
  padding: initial;
}

#popover .btn-container .btn-lg {
  display: inline-flex;
    border-radius: 6px;
    opacity: 1;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: -0.2px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-block: 5px !important;
    padding-inline: 15px;
    height: 26px !important;
}

#popover.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btn:enabled.btn-primary {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), rgb(0, 122, 255);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 122, 255, 0.2);
    color: white;
}

.btn:enabled.btn-active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: white;
    color: var(--light-text-primary);
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-family: var(--dark-font-family);
    transition: 0.3s;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding-inline: 15px;
    padding-block: 2px;
    border: none;
    height: 20px;
}

.btn:enabled {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div id="popover" class="hide">
    <img src="icon-none.png" alt="No Icon" class="pop-img">
    <h2>Modal Title</h2>
    <p>Modal Content</p>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Label</button>
      <button id="close-btn" class="btn btn-lg btn-active">Label</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
// Get the button and popover modal elements
const button = document.getElementById('popover-btn');
const popover = document.getElementById('popover');
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');

// When the button is clicked, show the popover modal
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popover.classList.remove('hide');
});

// When the close button is clicked, hide the popover modal
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popover.classList.add('hide');
});

// When the user clicks outside of the popover modal, hide it
window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target !== button && event.target !== popover && !popover.contains(event.target)) {
    popover.classList.add('hide');
  }
});
```

I have the `.btn-lg` class used elsewhere with the exact same code and that works fine, but just in the popover it doesn't work.

Expected and resulted image
[image: Expected and resulted image]

Answer (score 0):

using flexbox button text center verically

try it its work fine

```
.btn-group {
     display:flex;
     align-items:center;
     justify-content:center;
}

.btn {
     display:flex;
     align-items:center;
     justify-content:center;
}
```